# Validation code problems?

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have some code written in javascript that validates entered numbers in a field based on a set of allowable numbers.The problem im having is that even if i enter the right numbers it returns false. Here is my code:

```
window.onload=function() {

var validNumbers = {
 "2474": 2474,
 "2750": 2750,
 "2753": 2753,
 "2760": 2760,
 "2777": 2777
};
function validate(num) {
return typeof validNumbers[num] !== "undefined";
};

var button = document.getElementById("submit"),
userInput = document.getElementById("post");
button.onclick = function(event) {
alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
};
}

<form name="eoiform" form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi">

<input type="text" id="post" name="post"><?php echo $msgp; ?></td>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Could anyone provide some insight on my mistakes? Or possibly a better way to write this out?

Comment: You do know your validate function never gets called?

Comment: It still works on the basis of clicking the submit button so i dont think it needs to be called?

Comment: You have a stray "form" word in your form tag and also have a stray </td> tag in the form

Comment: @francis, what do you mean by "it works on the basis of clicking the submit button"?  The only function that gets called when the button is clicked is the one that alerts the user that their entered postcode is incorrect (which is why that's always the result you get), not the function which checks for correctness.

Comment: That would be my mistake, i know what he was referring to by it never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems complicated? just parse the inputted value as an integer, and check it against an array, if the value exists in the array, submit the form, if not alert the message and return false.

You should validate on the submit event, as there are other ways to submit a form than just clicking a button (like hitting enter in the input box).

Place the script after the HTML, and get rid of that window.onload at the same time :

```
<form name="eoiform" form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi">
    <input type="text" id="post" name="post"><?php echo $msgp; ?></td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var form         = document.getElementById('eoi'),
        validNumbers = [2474,
                        2750,
                        2753,
                        2760,
                        2777
                       ];

    form.onsubmit = function() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("post"),
            numb      = parseInt(userInput.value, 10);

        if ( validNumbers.indexOf(numb) == -1 ) {
            alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6q8NX/)

Comment: That all worked perfectly and thank you for the extra information!

Comment: @francis - sidenote: this uses Array.indexOf, which isn't supported in older versions of IE, but there is a polyfill available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?  considering your validate function NEVER get's called.

```
var validNumbers = {
    "2474": 2474,
    "2750": 2750,
    "2753": 2753,
    "2760": 2760,
    "2777": 2777
};

function validate(num) {
    return typeof validNumbers[num] !== "undefined";
};

var button = document.getElementById("submit"),
    userInput = document.getElementById("post");

button.onclick = function(event) {
    var val = validate(userInput.value)
    if(!val) {
        alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Thanks");
        // Run your code here
        // Form will submit
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7SxE/